# How to create a custom drop down control list in Google Data Studio? (using multi category column or multiple binary columns)

Tags: looker-studio

My use case is that one of the columns in my table has multiple categories included. For example, entry 1 may say *budget, schedule*, entry 2 may say *schedule, quality* and entry 3 may say *schedule*. I can also change it so that *budget, schedule and quality* become boolean columns.

I would like to create a drop down option that list each grade level individually and when one of the categories is selected,  I want the table to filter based on the selection in the drop down. So when someone selects *schedule*, all 3 entries, in this scenario, will be displayed.

Do you believe this is possible to do in Data Studio?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a parameter `cat_select` to filter the data.

[image]

Create a calculated field `cat_test` with

```
CONTAINS_TEXT(lower(categories),lower(cat_select))
```

[image]

Generate a filter for that field `cat_test` to be true.